# How can I access 'this' within a Mutation Observer callback in a class?

Tags: javascript, class, mutation-observers

I have a JavaScript class where I'd like to have a mutation observer to check when some nodes are added to a `div`. So in my constructor, I have something like this :

```js
class MyClass{
    constructor(){
        this.prop1 = "stuff";
        this.prop2 = 18;
        this._myObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
            if (mutations[0].addedNodes.length > 0){
               //do some stuff
            }
        });
    }

    myMethod(){
        //do stuff
        this._myObserver.observe(myNode, myParameters)
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

The goal here is to display (for the sake of the example) the content of `this.prop1` and calculate things with `this.prop2` when I add subnodes to `myNode`.

How can I access the other properties of my object within that callback function?

Comment: Ask only one question. Use arrow function callback to keep the class instance as `this`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer @trincot and the redirection
**edit** removed my second question.